# Is there a way to add new Filter method to Blazorise DataGrid component? For example, GreaterThan or LessThan for DataGridNumericColumn?

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm using Blazorise [DataGrid](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/features/filtering) component. The currently supported filtering methods include the following:

- **Contains** search for any occurrence (default)
- **StartsWith** search only the beginning
- **EndsWith** search only the ending
- **Equals** search must match the entire value
- **NotEquals** opposite of Equals

However, I have a need to filter a column with numeric values using **Greater Than** and **Less than** operators (filter methods).

I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Thank You for your help with this.

I was expecting that there is an example of extending the filter component to add the additional filter method.

Comment: I am not familiar with blazorise but you could  use a filter on the data source of the grid. This link should give you the idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935179/problem-showing-filtered-products-in-my-project-using-blazor/76935920#76935920