# Problem showing filtered products in my project using Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, filtering, user-input

I can't see the product filtering effect.
Maybe the problem is somewhere in my code?

I put the breakpoints in the lines and everything looks fine.
My goal is to do a filtering of products that are arranged in a table. For now, I'm doing filtering by each column. The code I wrote should perform filtering immediately while typing in the input field, but it doesn't work!

```
@using BlazorAppOluja.Shared.Modules
@using System.Threading.Tasks

@if (ProductService == null)
{
    <span>Error receiving products</span>
}
else
{
    <h3>Product Filter (Alternative)</h3>
    <input value="@TitleFilter" @oninput="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Title" />
    <input value="@DescriptionFilter" @oninput="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Description" />
    <input value="@PriceFilter" @oninput="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Price" />

    @if (products == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in filteredProducts)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Title</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td>@product.Price</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}

@code {
    private string TitleFilter = "";
    private string DescriptionFilter = "";
    private string PriceFilter = "";
    private List<Product> products;
    private List<Product> filteredProducts = new List<Product>();

    [Inject]
    private IProductService ProductService { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        products = await ProductService.GetProducts();
        UpdateFilteredProducts();
    }

    private void UpdateFilteredProducts()
    {
        filteredProducts = products
            .Where(p => p.Title.Contains(TitleFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                        p.Description.Contains(DescriptionFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                        p.Price.ToString().Contains(PriceFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToList();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are never actually setting the filter values from the inputs.

Here's a MRE based on `FetchData`, that demonstrates something similar to your code above working.

Note I use `IEnumerable`.  Think of this as query that only gets materialized when you iterate it.  Here, when the render block executes the code.

Modified `FetchData`.

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SO76935179.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

Summary:
<input @bind="_summaryFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="DoFilter" />
Temperature:
<input type="number" @bind="_temparatureFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="DoFilter" />

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>? forecasts;
    private string? _summaryFilter;
    private int? _temparatureFilter;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        DoFilter();
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void DoFilter()
    {
        // Build the query as an IEnumerable
        var query = ForecastService.WeatherForecasts;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_summaryFilter))
            query = query.Where(item => item.Summary is not null && item.Summary.Contains(_summaryFilter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (_temparatureFilter is not null)
            query = query.Where(item => item.TemperatureC == _temparatureFilter);

        forecasts = query;
    }
}
```

My modified `WeatherForecastService`.

```cs
namespace SO76935179.Data
{
    public class WeatherForecastService
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts => _weatherForecasts ?? Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();

        private List<WeatherForecast>? _weatherForecasts;

        public WeatherForecastService()
        {
            _weatherForecasts = GetForecasts(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)); 
        }

        private List<WeatherForecast> GetForecasts(DateOnly startDate)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My colleague and I found that the problem was in the 'oninput event'. No matter how you try to write it in a different way, the code will not filter the input in the input field. Now we **don't know** exactly how to solve that problem. If you have any advice for us, it would help us a lot :).

Comment: [Polite] Read the answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

MrC aka Shaun Curtis is correct you have to set the fields before your using them. Thats you problem here:

```
 <input @bind="TitleFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Title" />
 <input @bind="DescriptionFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Description" />
 <input @bind="PriceFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Price" />
```

Full working sample (I removed the servicecall for simplicity) :

```
@page "/"

@if (filteredProducts is null)
{
    <span>Error receiving products</span>
}
else
{
    <h3>Product Filter (Alternative)</h3>
    <input @bind="TitleFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Title" />
    <input @bind="DescriptionFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Description" />
    <input @bind="PriceFilter" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="UpdateFilteredProducts" placeholder="Filter Price" />

    @if (products == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var product in filteredProducts)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Title</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td>@product.Price</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}

@code {
    private string TitleFilter = "";
    private string DescriptionFilter = "";
    private string PriceFilter = "";
    private List<Product> products;
    private List<Product> filteredProducts = new List<Product>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        filteredProducts = new List<Product>();
        products = await GetProducts();
    }

    private void UpdateFilteredProducts()
    {
        filteredProducts = products
            .Where(p => p.Title.Contains(TitleFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                        p.Description.Contains(DescriptionFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                        p.Price.ToString().Contains(PriceFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToList();
     
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<List<Product>> GetProducts()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Title = "A",
                Description = "Adesc",
                Price = "100"
            },
            new Product
            {
                Title = "b",
                Description = "Bdesc",
                Price = "1100"
            },
            new Product
            {
                Title = "C",
                Description = "Cdesc",
                Price = "1400"
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I think we had the same idea of simplifying MrC's answer so that it was more familiar for the OP.

Comment: My colleague and I found that the problem was in the 'oninput event'. No matter how you try to write it in a different way, the code will not filter the input in the input field. Now we don't know exactly how to solve that problem. If you have any advice for us, it would help us a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

The local fields (`TitleFilter,DescriptionFilter,PriceFilter`) are not being set from the inputs.

There's various ways this can be done ,as[@MrC has demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76935743/11779494).

Here's one way,

In the code below, we handle the changing of the fields in the `UpdateFilteredProducts` method by passing the reference of the fields and then modifying it before performing the filtering on the products list.

```
<input value="TitleFilter" @oninput="(args)=>UpdateFilteredProducts(args,ref TitleFilter)" placeholder="Filter Title"/>
<input value="DescriptionFilter" @oninput="(args)=>UpdateFilteredProducts(args,ref DescriptionFilter)" placeholder="Filter Description" />
<input value="PriceFilter" @oninput="(args)=>UpdateFilteredProducts(args,ref PriceFilter)" placeholder="Filter Price" />
@code{
    private void UpdateFilteredProducts(ChangeEventArgs args,ref string changedField)
    {
        changedField = args.Value.ToString();
        filteredProducts = products.Where(p => p.Title.Contains(TitleFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    p.Description.Contains(DescriptionFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    p.Price.ToString().Contains(PriceFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: My colleague and I found that the problem was in the 'oninput event'. No matter how you try to write it in a different way, the code will not filter the input in the input field. Now we don't know exactly how to solve that problem. If you have any advice for us, it would help us a lot :).

Comment: Yes, look at the answers.

Comment: [Polite] Shorter, yes,  Simpler?   Anyway, it looks like we've wasted our time based on the OP comment!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, looks like it. Oh well hopefully it'll help someone else.